# Travis CI: Deploy JAR to Github Releases

Tags: travis-ci, github-release

I want to use Travis to create nice posts in Github Releases after commit in master

This is what I need:

- establish custom title
- establish custom description
- Publish only build without source code zip

I tried everything I could, but I could only add the binary to the release. Here is my config:

```
language: java
sudo: false
install: gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.2
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
script:
- chmod +x gradlew
- "./gradlew test"
- "./gradlew build"
- "./gradlew jar"
- cd build # test
- ls
- cd libs
- ls
- pwd
- echo $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
cache:
  directories:
  - "$HOME/.gradle"
  - ".gradle"
before_deploy:
  # Set up git user name and tag this commit
  - git config --local user.name "RareScrap"
  - git config --local user.email "RareScrap@users.noreply.github.com"
  - export GIT_TAG=$TRAVIS_BRANCH-v0.1.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
  - git tag $GIT_TAG -a -m "Generated tag from TravisCI for build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [redacted]
  file: "/home/travis/build/RareScrap/travis.test/build/libs/*"
  skip_cleanup: true
  file_glob: true
  on:
    repo: RareScrap/travis.test
    branches:    # ← new! ghjgjghjghjghj
          only:      # ← new!
            - master # ← new!
```

Answer (score 2):

The GitHub Releases API can accept:

- [String] name - Name for the release
- [String] body - Content for release notes
- [Boolean] draft - Mark this release as a draft
- [Boolean] prerelease - Mark this release as a pre-release

[Source](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/lib/octokit/client/releases.rb).

As for only on `master`, use `on` instead of `only`.

Therefore, simply add change your deploy:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [redacted]
  file: "/home/travis/build/RareScrap/travis.test/build/libs/*"
  skip_cleanup: true
  file_glob: true
  on:
    repo: RareScrap/travis.test
    branches:    # ← new! ghjgjghjghjghj
          only:      # ← new!
            - master # ← new!
```

to this:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [redacted]
  file: "/home/travis/build/RareScrap/travis.test/build/libs/*"
  skip_cleanup: true
  file_glob: true
  on:
    repo: RareScrap/travis.test
    branch: master
  name: $YOUR_RELEASE_NAME
  body: $YOUR_RELEASE_CONTENT
```

Feel free to reference [my .travis.yml file](https://github.com/Samasaur1/Utilities/blob/master/.travis.yml) where I did a very similar thing.

Hope this helps!